# Is there away to use SetEnvIf with host and ip address?

Tags: .htaccess, setenv, typo3-flow

I'm using setenvif like so:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^dev\.mydomain\.com$ FLOW_CONTEXT=Development
SetEnvIf Host ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ FLOW_CONTEXT=Production
```

What I want to know is, can I also somehow restrict dev.mydomain.com to an IP address? So that the world and his dog can't see my site in Development context?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to limit access but it generally depends on how you've setup your `dev` and `www` sites. If they share the same document roots and you don't have access to dev's vhost config then you can do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.34\.56\.78$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

SO if the host is `dev.mydomain.com` and the remote IP *isn't* 12.34.56.78, then deny access.

Otherwise, from the dev vhost you can just do:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 12.34.56.78
Deny from All
```